# Double injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection

We use injections a lot and here comes arhcitectural question - who and when should implement it.

Let's take simple example. Class Farm can handle Plantable object which are injected. It could be Trees, Vegetables, etc. Each Plantable object has ways to be Startable (planted) which is injected too.

Question is who is responsible for second injection? If it is Farm then it should be smart enough to know all possible Plantable objects and so Farm became god object. If it is Tree then it should be complicated object to use reflection and to know about Farm which has it. Instead of being simple Plantable object which should take care of itself it should be aware of environments, possible types of Farms, etc.

External configuration file like Spring configuration is not the solution because number of all types objects is big and dynamic.

Ideally Plantable and Startable objects should be added on the fly and take care of themseves and don't depend on each other as it should be in OOP world.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe this question would be more on-topic in [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It seems to me your question is not about dependency injection, but about object creation patterns.

Comment: Are `Farm`, `Plantable`, `Tree` and `Vegatable` actual objects in your application? It is really hard to discuss these subjects over abstract examples instead the real design. My experience is that questions about DI are actually questions about application design and you can't discuss application design when abstract or imaginary type names are used. So it is best to rename the type names and use the actual names you use in your application.

Comment: @Alex Have you heard of the `Abstract factory` pattern?

Comment: @Steven - I tried to explain and used some common words for explanation. There are a lot of classes which inherit Farm and objects which inherit Plantable which use objects of Startable type.

Comment: @Chetan Kinger - to be honest I didn't hear about Abstract Factory pattern. I took a look at it and, in my opinion, it just describes issue what I'm facing. Each Concrete Product knows and works with Concrete Factory. I want it one level up - Abstract Product works with Abstract Factory and all what I have to care is implementation of individuality of the Concrete classes. I'll think about it.

Comment: @Alex Posting this as the answer.

Comment: If you add one more interface to you upper class (Farm) ProvideEnvironment() then lower level (Plantable) should not know all about  this exact Farm and your implementations will be separate and independent.

Comment: Please add some code samples of your classes, and if you can, please use the real class names and method names that you use in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern.

From `Head first design patterns` :

> Provides an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete types.

Comment: I almost agree. Because what I had described fits good to the Abstract Factory pattern. It is Abstract Factory pattern. But my struggle is with implementation. Question was how to implement it without Factory knowing about Products and Products knowing about Factories. Even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) provides explanation with example of different AbstractProductA connected to AbstractFactoryA which is some dependency. But I'll use this approach with simplification for one AbstractFactory, one AbstractProduct and communication between via these interfaces